# Greek characters in text file on Isolated storage

Tags: windows-phone-7

The problem is coming when i read a file from the Isolated storage using StreamReader. 
The Greek characters are appears as ??????
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: The font you're displaying the characters with doesn't have any greek character glyphs.  [Edit] and add info about how you are displaying the characters (textblock?  what font?  etc)

Comment: its a TextBlock and the Greek its OK on it

Comment: :| you mean if you don't serialize/deserialize it shows the greek text correctly?  Can you [edit] and add the code you are using to read/write this text to isolated storage?

Comment: I mean when i'm writing something to the textblock it shows correct the Greek. When i'm reading the file, the greek letters are ???????

Comment: Can you edit and add the code you are using to read/write this text to isolated storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saved the file in Unicode format and its ok now